# Wrong starting and ending on TranslateTransition in Javafx

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

I am trying to simulate sorting algorithms. So I need to move two numbers to show swap between them. But most of the time it's starting moving from wrong place to another wrong place. Here is the code where I am using TranslateTransition:

```
public static void showSwap(Text t1, Text t2)
{
    double x1, x2, z;
    x1=t1.getX();
    x2=t2.getX();
    z=x2-x1;

    pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(1000));

    t1up = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), t1);
    t1up.setFromY(0);
    t1up.setToY(-55);
    t1up.setCycleCount(1);

    t1right = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), t1);
    t1right.setFromX(0);
    t1right.setToX(z);
    t1right.setCycleCount(1);

    t1down = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), t1);
    t1down.setFromY(-55);
    t1down.setToY(0);
    t1down.setCycleCount(1);
    t1.toFront();
    sequentialTransition1.getChildren().addAll(t1up,t1right,t1down,pt);

    t2down = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), t2);
    t2down.setFromY(0);
    t2down.setToY(55);
    t2down.setCycleCount(1);

    t2left = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), t2);
    t2left.setFromX(0);
    t2left.setToX(-z);
    t2left.setCycleCount(1);

    t2up = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), t2);
    t2up.setFromY(55);
    t2up.setToY(0);
    t2up.setCycleCount(1);
    t2.toFront();
    sequentialTransition2.getChildren().addAll(t2down,t2left,t2up,pt);
}
```

I also tried this part, but it got NullPointerException.

```
public static void showSwap2(Text t1, Text t2)
{
    double x1, x2, y;
    x1=t1.getX();
    x2=t2.getX();
    y=t1.getY();

    MoveTo start1 = new MoveTo( x1, y );

    ArcTo end1 = new ArcTo();
    end1.setX(x2);
    end1.setY(y);
    end1.setRadiusX(100);
    end1.setRadiusY(100);

    Path path1 = new Path();
    path1.getElements().addAll(start1, end1);

    PathTransition transition1 = new PathTransition();
    transition1.setDuration(Duration.millis(900));
    transition1.setPath(path1);
    sequentialTransition1.getChildren().addAll(transition1);

    MoveTo start2 = new MoveTo( x1, y );

    ArcTo end2 = new ArcTo();
    end2.setX(x2);
    end2.setY(y);
    end2.setRadiusX(100);
    end2.setRadiusY(100);

    Path path2 = new Path();
    path2.getElements().addAll( start2, end2 );

    PathTransition transition2 = new PathTransition();
    transition2.setDuration(Duration.millis(900));
    transition2.setPath(path2);
    sequentialTransition2.getChildren().addAll(transition2);

}
```

Here is the part from where I am calling showSwap() method:

```
public final class BubbleSort extends SimulatorController implements Initializable
{
    public BubbleSort(Pane root,int totalNumbers)
    {
        int i, j, temp;

        for (i = totalNumbers - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Simulator.showCompare(rect.get(j), rect.get(j+1));
                if (numbers.get(j) > numbers.get(j + 1))
                {
                    Simulator.showSwap(textNumbers.get(j),textNumbers.get(j+1));
                    temp = numbers.get(j);
                    numbers.set(j,numbers.get(j+1));
                    numbers.set(j+1,temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the controller class:

```
public class SimulatorController  implements Initializable
{
    @FXML protected Canvas img ;
    @FXML protected Button prev;
    @FXML protected Button next;
    @FXML protected BorderPane root;

    protected static SequentialTransition sequentialTransition1;
    protected static SequentialTransition sequentialTransition2;
    protected int totalNumbers=5;
    protected static boolean nextMove=false;
    protected static boolean prevMove=false;
    protected static boolean simulateAutomatically=false;
    protected static ArrayList<Rectangle> rect = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    protected static ArrayList<Text> textNumbers=new ArrayList<Text>();
    protected ArrayList<Text> textIndex=new ArrayList<Text>();
    protected static ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    protected ArrayList<Integer> index=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    protected static TranslateTransition t1right;
    protected static TranslateTransition t1up;
    protected static TranslateTransition t1down;
    protected static TranslateTransition t2left;
    protected static TranslateTransition t2down;
    protected static TranslateTransition t2up;
    protected static PauseTransition pt;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) 
    {
        drawArrayAndNumbers();

        sequentialTransition1 = new SequentialTransition();         sequentialTransition2 = new SequentialTransition();         sequentialTransition1.setCycleCount(1);         sequentialTransition2.setCycleCount(1);

        new BubbleSort(root,totalNumbers);

        sequentialTransition1.play();        
        sequentialTransition2.play();


      root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
      {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                  System.out.println(("X="+mouseEvent.getScreenX()+" || Y="+mouseEvent.getScreenY()));
            }
          });
    }

    void drawArrayAndNumbers()
    {
        int i, x=50, y=250, rectSizeX=70, rectsizeY=50;
        for(i=0;i<totalNumbers;i++,x+=rectSizeX+35)
        {
            rect.add(i, new Rectangle(x, y, rectSizeX, rectsizeY));
            rect.get(i).setArcHeight(10);
            rect.get(i).setArcWidth(10);
            rect.get(i).setFill(Color.SKYBLUE);

            numbers.add(i,100+(int)(Math.random()*899));
            index.add(i);

            textNumbers.add(i, new Text (x+15, y+30, Integer.toString(numbers.get(i))));
            textNumbers.get(i).setFill(Color.BLACK);
            textNumbers.get(i).setFont(new Font(25));

            textIndex.add(i, new Text (x+30, y+rectsizeY+15, Integer.toString(i)));
            textIndex.get(i).setFill(Color.BLACK);
            textIndex.get(i).setFont(new Font(15));

            root.getChildren().addAll(rect.get(i),textNumbers.get(i),textIndex.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

This is the screenshot after completing the TranslateTrasitions. I need to keep the numbers within the box. But They are not moving to right place.

[Here, before starting the animation, the texts within the rectangle were 944 701 666 503 531. After completing the animation, the rectangles should contain the numbers 503 531 666 701 944. But it was showing those.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnWVB.png)

How can I solve these problems?

Here is the download link of full package: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7pxly3GctSNQ1FaajY4LTFOQnM&usp=sharing

Comment: I tried your first version, adding the minimal amount I could to make it into an executable example, and it worked just fine. Therefore your errors are in other parts of your code. Please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] which demonstrates the problem (that way you are guaranteed your question includes whatever it is you're doing wrong).

Comment: Not the `x` and `y` properties, but the `translateX` and the `translateY` properties are animated. This messes up your calculation for previously moved nodes.

Comment: @James_D
The first version does not work most of the time here. I have  tried to add more to clarify. I have uploaded full package on google drive and have provided that link too. Please let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: @fabian
I could not get that what I have to do. Is it possible to specify a new coordinate to move? Like, here I need to  move text1  to the X-axis position of text2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `x` and `y` positions of `Text`. This however this is a property not common to all `Node`s. The properties animated are the `translateX` and `translateY` properties. Therefore

```
x1=t1.getX();
x2=t2.getX();
z=x2-x1;
```

results in `z` being the difference between the difference between the origin's x coordinates, not the difference between the locations after the previous transition. Furthermore you call this before the animation is done, so even if you fix the issue mentioned before, you use the current locations for the calculations, not the position of the `Node`s after the previous animation.

To fix this, save the initial positions and use the `translate` properties to position the nodes:

```
public class SwapAnimationQueue<T extends Node> {

    private final SequentialTransition transitionUpper;
    private final SequentialTransition transitionLower;
    private final T[] nodes;
    private final double[] positionX;

    public SwapAnimationQueue(T... nodes) {
        this.transitionLower = new SequentialTransition();
        this.transitionUpper = new SequentialTransition();

        this.nodes = nodes.clone();
        positionX = new double[nodes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            positionX[i] = nodes[i].getTranslateX();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        this.transitionLower.play();
        this.transitionUpper.play();
    }

    public void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        if (index1 == index2) {
            return;
        }
        T temp;
        createTransition(transitionUpper, index1, index2, temp = nodes[index1], true);
        createTransition(transitionLower, index2, index1, nodes[index2], false);
        nodes[index1] = nodes[index2];
        nodes[index2] = temp;
    }

    private void createTransition(SequentialTransition transition, int startPosition, int endPosition, Node node, boolean upper) {
        double dy = upper ? -55 : 55;
        TranslateTransition vertical1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), node);
        vertical1.setByY(dy);

        TranslateTransition horizontal = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), node);
        horizontal.setByX(positionX[endPosition] - positionX[startPosition]);

        TranslateTransition vertical2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900), node);
        vertical2.setByY(-dy);

        transition.getChildren().addAll(vertical1, horizontal, vertical2);
    }

}
```

Alternatively for the round transitions:

```
private void createTransition(SequentialTransition transition, int startPosition, int endPosition, Node node, boolean upper) {
    double x1 = positionX[startPosition];
    double x2 = positionX[endPosition];
    MoveTo move = new MoveTo(x1, node.getTranslateY());

    double radius = Math.abs(x2-x1) / 2;

    ArcTo arc = new ArcTo(radius, 20, 0, x2-x1, 0, upper, true);
    arc.setAbsolute(false);

    transition.getChildren().add(new PathTransition(Duration.millis(900), new Path(move, arc), node));
}
```

### Usage

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    String[] text = {"3", "2", "1"};

    Text[] textNodes = new Text[text.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        Text t = new Text(text[i]);
        t.setTranslateX(20 + i * 50);
        t.setTranslateY(100);
        textNodes[i] = t;
    }

    SwapAnimationQueue swapper = new SwapAnimationQueue(textNodes);
    Pane p = new Pane();

    p.getChildren().addAll(textNodes);

    swapper.swap(0, 1);
    swapper.swap(1, 2);
    swapper.swap(0, 1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(p, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    swapper.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much MR. Fabian. Finally I have successfully implemented your given code. Now it is working very fine, as I needed.